# Error : You have an error with your sql syntax, check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB for the right syntax

Tags: java, mysql, mariadb

I have a java program that create a new database then create a table into it. But when I run the program, it say I have an error in my SQL syntax like this

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE barang (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,nama VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,ju' at line 1

Here is my code :

```
try {
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASS);
    int answer = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(this, "Database tidak ditemukan, ingin membuat baru?", "Database not found", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, null, null);
    if (answer == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
        st = con.createStatement();
        String sql = ("CREATE DATABASE afifdb;"
                    + "CREATE TABLE barang ("
                    + "id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,"
                    + "nama VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,"
                    + "jumlah INT(11),"
                    + "tanggal DATE,"
                    + "kondisi VARCHAR(20),"
                    + "keterangan VARCHAR(100),"
                    + "PRIMARY KEY (id)"
                    + ");");
        st.executeUpdate(sql);
    }
} catch (HeadlessException | SQLException e3) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Gagal. ERROR : " + e3);
}
```

Sorry I using my language in this program, hope you don't mind it. I'll appreciate any supports you give. Thanks.

Comment: For a start I would try using different statements for each sql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`executeUpdate()` is [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html) as:

> Executes the given SQL statement, which may be an INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement or an SQL statement that returns nothing, such as an SQL DDL statement.

Note the *singular*.  Your code has two SQL statements.

Try splitting it into two separate calls.

Just as a check, your `create table` syntax [looks correct](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=305b2b6c8fab2db1cf193aca530028d1).